# Format URL with the system date in bash

Tags: bash, shell, curl, cron

I would run a .sh script to execute an operation from a server only if the given URL is up.
The URL where I get data updates everyday (but I dont know exactly what time it updates).

A cron job would run this script every five minutes and as soon as the updated URL exists, it runs an Rscript.
I don't know curl or bash enough to update the date according to the system's.

I thought of writing a code in BASH that would look like this :

```
 if curl -s --head  --request GET https://example.com-2021-05-10 | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null; then 
   Rscript ~/mybot.R
else
   echo "the page is not up yet"
 fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `date` command.

```sh
 if curl -s --head  --request GET https://example.com-$(date '+%Y-%M-%d') | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null; then 
   Rscript ~/mybot.R
else
   echo "the page is not up yet"
 fi
```